# What is an association bonus?

Tags: support

Under what circumstances, could a StackExchange user win an association bonus? I tried to find it out, but could not?

Comment: I don't think you searched hard enough: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/

Comment: @KyleKanos It is unreasonable to expect every newcomer to be aware of that site. @ abstract: there exists a 'mother meta' site on which you can discuss all general StackExchange network issues, and which you should search for this kind of information, at http://meta.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Kyle Kanos: Yes, I admit, that I did not try hard enough , but I did try whatever I could, under current inevitable circumstances.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty: of course it would be unreasonable for new users to know about the mother meta. However, the link I provided is one of the top hits on a Google search for "association bonus stack exchange". I think it is perfectly reasonable to expect questioners to have tried a Google search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Next time, search [the help center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation):

> If you are an experienced Stack Exchange network user with 200 or more reputation on at least one site, you will receive a starting +100 reputation bonus to get you past basic new user restrictions. This will happen automatically on all current Stack Exchange sites where you have an account, and on any other Stack Exchange sites at the time you log in.